# Does the letter p in a word mean that the word is not Germanic?

Tags: historical-linguistics, germanic-languages, sound-change

In Germanic languages, the p sound in Proto-Indo-European became f. I have wondered if the p sound means that the word does not come from a Germanic source. This is because words that have p in them usually come from Latin. Does the presence of that letter mean that the word is not Germanic?

Comment: If just the presence of just the letter p by itself would make the word non-Germanic, there are a lot of non-Germanic words in German.

Comment: @Mast There _are_ a lot of non-Germanic words in German. But also German underwent a second shift (the High German consonant shift or) which devoiced the voices plosives. That shift only applied generally to /b/ (turning it into /p/) in High German in the south, but it applied to geminate /bː/ throughout, hence pairs like Eng _rib_, Ger _Rippe_. But most of the p’s that appear in Modern German are indeed in loan words from non-Germanic languages (primarily French/Latin), and many of the actual, Germanic p’s are now (p)f’s in German (_auf_, _apfel_, etc.).

Comment: And than, there are three odd words out there, I quote the High German forms first: *Pfad* "path", *Pflug* "plough" (with the verb *Pflügen* "to plough"), and *pflegen* "to care" (formerly a strong verb in German) where no outer-germanic borrowing relation is really confirmed.

Answer (score 24):

### Not always.

Grimm's Law predicts that Proto-Indo-European **b* would turn into Proto-Germanic **p*. However, Proto-Indo-European **b* is vanishingly rare, and some scholars argue it didn't actually exist in the oldest reconstructable forms of the language (only appearing later). Regardless, though, an ancestral **b* is probably the source of a few native Germanic words like English "a**pp**le", cognate with Russian *ja**b**loko* and Gaulish *a**b**alom*.

Grimm's Law also had certain exceptions where it didn't apply. The most common of these is after **s*, which gives us native Germanic words like English "s**p**ew", cognate with Latin *s**p**uō*, or "s**p**rout", (probably) cognate with Ancient Greek *s**p**eírō*.

Comment: There are also some cases of PG _*b_ (from PIE _*bʰ_ or _*p_ with Verner’s Law) followed by a nasal yielding _*pp_, though the only example I can think of this early in the morning is PIE _*upó-_ > PG _*ub-_ + _-nó-_ > _*upp(a)-_ > ‘up’.

Comment: there's also plenty of non-native vocabulary that's solidly reconstrucable at the proto-Germanic stage. This is still (arguably) Germanic, as it is present at such an early point, even if it was borrowed from some other language (whether that other language was IE or pre-IE varies by word ofc)

Comment: Well, apple is probably a bad example word since the names of fruits are often *wanderwörter*. Looking up when and where the cultivation of apples started it is not clear whether Protoindogermanic already could have a word for apple or not.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica True, but it does seem to show a fairly consistent `/p/` in Germanic and `/b/` elsewhere, which implies it was borrowed before Grimm's Law happened.

Comment: @Draconis, maybe it's the reason Krimm's Lau happened, we really don't no

Comment: @vectory Sorry, are you suggesting that the word _apple_ is the cause of Grimm's Law?

Comment: I am not, it's suggesting itself, as a potentially relevant factor perhaps because it meant fruit in general, ModHG *ab-fallen* "fall off" is what they do, whereas transitive *abfallen für mich* (for me) means "to have a share in", "enjoy the fruits of" as much as idiomatic "für'n Appel und 'n Ei" (for an appel and a egg) implies its significance as payment in a sharing economy; cp. *obolus*. Just for a start.

Comment: @vectory When we see a root which has clear cognates with `/b/` in Celtic and Slavic, but `/p/` in Germanic, that seems very clearly to be the _result_ of Grimm's Law, not its cause. Languages don't completely rearrange their phonemic inventories because "hey it might be cool if we started pronouncing 'apple' with a `/p/`".

Comment: a) *Appel* > *Apfel* is typical for the *second* consonant shift. I hadn't payed attention to that, but might repose that it was a continuous development from the first. b) the *cause* of the first shift, i.e. grimm's ley, is in your view *completely arbitrary*. There's nothing to argue about. c) Celtic and Slavic speakers mingling with Germanic speakers, if there had been such a clear distinction to begin with, would be the ideal breading ground for sound change. Obviously we have no clear picture. d) *Appel* is in fact often voiced in vernacular, i.e. *Abbl*.

Comment: PS: "Heyna it might be kewl if ..." is the motto of low prestige dialects immitating the ruling class dialect. That's not not [sic!] rare

Comment: Bonus: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Proto-Germanic_terms_derived_from_Latin Compare especially \*kaupo "to cop, buy" (uncertain), *cobbler* (uncertain), Ger. *kaufen* "buy", also *haven*, *Copenhagen*, Ger. *Hafen*, *Haff*, *Habsburg*, *Hannover* ... Otherwise *Blatt* "leavelett", *platt* "flat"; Also perhaps *poulet* "chicken" vs *Vo'l* ~ *Vogel* "bird, fowl" (unlikely, I just started bird watching). None of which denies the answers given here.

Answer (score 15):

No, because PIE *p does not always become *f*. It does not in the cluster *sp*, for example "spin" < *spen, "sprawl" < *sper. Germanic *p* regularly derives from *b*, e.g. "deep" < *\dheub. Germanic *swompuz "swamp; fungus" is attested in all branches of Germanic as well as Greek σομφός: the reconstruction *su̯omb(h)o-s is a bit of a problem because of the variability in aspiration. Nevertheless, it's clear that those instances of "p" are in Germanic words. Other examples are "apple" and possible "peg" < *bak

Comment: Sumpf is probably a variant of Tümpel, rel. *dew*. The Greek can hardly be directly from \*su-, cp. *hexa* "6", initial s was regularly not maintained

Comment: As @vectory says, the equation σομφός : *swamp* is quite doubtful -- one phonological mismatch (*p*:φ) in an etymology is bad enough, but two (*s-*:σ-) are probably fatal.

Answer (score 4):

Even in the case that the /p-/ is word initial, there are some words of Germanic origin containing it due to some irregularities mainly. As an example I quote the word *Patzer* (mainly known as a term for a bad chess player via Yiddish, but a more general word in High German) that is related to the regular High German word *Batzen* "heap, pile, lump", the initial P is a typical Upper German (Bavarian and Alemannic) dialectal feature. *Packen* "paket" is another example, in this case related to *backen* "to bake".